# Storing Azure Function secrets: Startup.Configure is not executed

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function application. The secrets are stored in local.settings.json and also in secrets.json:

```
{
  "Values": {
  "BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME": "<USERNAME>",
  "BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD": "<PASSWORD>"
  }
}
```

The Azure function code that consumes the secrets:

```
        string username = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        string password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Here https://www.koskila.net/how-to-configure-azure-functions-startup/ I found how to add startup.cs file with the Startup class and Configure function:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace LATICRETE.IdentityFunctions
{
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

But the GetEnvironmentVariable() method returns only null, and the Startup.Configure() method is never executed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to update your code as per below snippet;

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Linq;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(LATICRETE.IdentityFunctions.Startup))]
namespace LATICRETE.IdentityFunctions
{
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            var executionContextOptions = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IOptions<ExecutionContextOptions>>().Value;
            var appDirectory = executionContextOptions.AppDirectory;

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(appDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange:true).AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            
        builder.Services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton(typeof(IConfiguration),
config));
        }
    }
}
```

And this code will be executed only the very first time when we run the project or when we deploy the code.
You can then inject the IConfiguration in which ever class you want and the config settings can be accessed from it's instance.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

public class TestClass{

  private readonly IConfiguration _config;
  
  public TestClass(IConfiguration config)
  {
    _config = config;
  }
  
  public void DoSomeThing()
  {
    var localSettingA = _config["localSettingA"];
  }
}
```

Need to import Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration to use IConfiguration.
Foe more information, have a look at this article - https://medium.com/@padala.suresh.ece/loading-keyvault-secrets-and-appsettings-in-to-application-configuration-in-azure-function-apps-c1798a8fd93f

Comment: Hi David, please register DI for Test class in Startup like - builder.Services.AddScoped<TestClass>();    And again to TestClass, try to inject it through constructor in your client class, just like how IConfiguration is injected/resolved in TestClass constructor

Comment: Thank you. But for some reason, the constructor is not called at all in my UnitTests class (I use XUnit).

Comment: Also, it is not clear why I would want to inject the TestClass into my client class (i.e. UnitTests).

Comment: I tried to create the TestClass with new () in my UnitTests, and pass to the TestClass constructor the IConfiguration object. That object I expected to be injected into the UnitTests() constructor. But as I mentioned, for some reason that constructor is not called...